# sed regex issues on aix

Tags: regex, sed, aix

Could one help translating following sed command so it does the same on aix ?

```
sed -e '/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,10\}\s\{1,5\}\"\)/!d'
```

Works fine on linux but on AIX it seem to do nothing

Comment: This regex matches a line that *starts with 1 to 10 alphanumeric chars followed by 1 to 5 spaces and a double quote(I don't think that escaping double quote is necessary)*, `!d` means to print the lines that match. the sed command looks ok to me, but I don't have an AIX box to test it out.

Comment: it seems there is a problem with double quote, no matter if escaped or not AIX doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so it turned out problem is related to blank space character "\s"

i replaced "\s" with escaped blank space "\ " and it works

```
sed -e '/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{1,10\}\ \{1,5\}\"\)/!d'
```